# Naming a file in matlab

Tags: matlab, naming

I currently have this:

```
[filename, pathname, filterindex] = uiputfile({...
   ... (various filetypes)   
    'Disks image.jpg');
    if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(pathname,0)
        disp('User selected Cancel');
    else
        disp(['User selected ',fullfile(pathname,filename)]);
    end
    imwrite(M, 'Disks image.jpg', 'jpg');
    disp('Image saved');
end
```

How would I write for the part currently saying 'Disks image.jpg' a name that is either the current time (given by the following):

```
dateTime = javaMethod('currentTimeMillis', 'java.lang.System');
```

Or a name that is a combination of both that and some other specified name (e.g. currentTimeMillis_Diffraction_pattern.jpg)

As I am saving two image files, it would be good if I can name the file by the second method, as it gives an ordered list without having to separate the two images into different file folders.

Using  time...........+..........._Diffraction_pattern.extension would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are using a Java function to get the time, rather than built in Matlab time function. I would just use

```
dateTimeString = datestr(now, 'yyyy-mm-dd-HH_MM_SS_FFF');
```

Then concatenate that with whatever name you want to create a file name:

```
myFileName = [dateTimeString '_withSomeName.jpg'];
imwrite( M, myFileName, 'jpg' );
```

Note - I think that if you include the `.jpg` extension on the file, it will automatically be converted by `imwrite` so you don't need the third argument. Also note that using the `FFF` format specifier will give you the time down to ms - so it's got the same functionality (and granularity) as your original Java function call, but results in more sensible file names.

If you insist on using the Java function, you need to convert it to Matlab's internal clock - this means something like this (untested):

```
timeNow = javaMethod('currentTimeMillis', 'java.lang.System');
timeMatlab = timeNow / (1000 * 3600 * 24) + datenum('1 Jan 1970');
dateTimeString = datestr(timeMatlab, 'yyyy-mm-dd-HH_MM_SS');
```

but why would you do that...

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation can be done like this:

```
filename=[num2str(dateTime) '_Diffraction_pattern.extension'];
```

Or using sprintf:

```
filename=sprintf('%d_Diffraction_pattern.extension',dateTime);
```